# is it possible to define a set of files in excel, to be opened together?

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have several sets of files, each set have severl excel files located in different folders that referring to each other's data, they have to be opened in one excel session for the VBA to properly run.

now i have to remember all these sets of files. is there a simple way in excel to group several files as a set, and to open them together by one click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Workspace. This article explains better than I ever could.

[Save workbooks in an arranged workspace](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-workbooks-in-an-arranged-workspace-9ab295e1-01a0-43aa-90f1-98c6fdeeb121)